# Which type of applications can use WebParts?

Tags: asp.net, web-parts

I tried using webparts on an asp.net webpage and got a blank screen. While googling, I came across this link

[simple web parts in asp.net show as blank page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672535/simple-web-parts-in-asp-net-show-as-blank-page)

which made me wondering, which type of applications should ideally use WebParts ? 
Please share your real world experiences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welll I know of ([Microsoft Office SharePoint](http://sharepoint2007.microsoft.com/Pages/Default.aspx) ,[Microsoft SharePoint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SharePoint))

[Walkthrough: Creating a Basic SharePoint Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452873.aspx)

Comment: @astander the webparts have been built in asp.net too, now their not only for Sharepoint.