# Switched to windows authentication in MVC and screen goes blank!

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows, authentication

Have switched to windows authentication in the debug mode, set NLTM in the project options but  when i press play it just gives me a blank screen! Any ideas what I can do now?

thanks!

Comment: reading this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2672535/simple-web-parts-in-asp-net-show-as-blank-page

seems to shed a little light....

Comment: read about: 

Exactly what happens when you attempt to invoke a controller action without being the right permissions depends on the type of authentication enabled. By default, when using the ASP.NET Development Server, you simply get a blank page. The page is served with a 401 Not Authorized HTTP Response Status.

ive added:   <customErrors defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx" mode="On">
          <error statusCode="401" redirect="AccessDenied.aspx" />
      </customErrors>

to my config but no redirection...

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes to this put just [authorize] rather than say

[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]

The blank screen is some kind of 401 response. if youre logged in you'll alwasy get through the [authorize] filter

Roles would seem to be a tricky area to get right